# StrapiJs- User authentication and user profile

Tags: social-networking, strapi

1) I built profile information content type in strapijs. Added user relation to it. Profile has and belongs to one user". Like a simple social media.

2)I added couple users/profile information. Connected it for spesific user.

3) Tested api with postman. Authentication works i can see profile information. But the problem is, when a user authenticated could access other users profile information.

How can i restrict one user to see only related profile? 
Thank you

Comment: Hello can you precise your 3. point please.
Because when you login, you receive your user object in the `user` key.
And that contains only your user information, so I don't understand.

Comment: Any authenticated user might see any user profile. I can't restrict a profile for certain user.

Comment: So a user can see only it's user info + his profile info? And could not see other users?

Comment: Exactly. We should apply new rules and change strapi source code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so for your use case you have to restrict `GET /users/` to all your users.
With that, no one will access to other data users.

But you can access to `GET /users/me/` route. And you will be able to access to the Auth User data.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible with current strapijs admin panel(at least i couldn't figure it out). I can restrict GET/users/ but not  GET /users/me/. In this case a user can't see all users but see other users profile with id's. We have to impy that policy via source code.

Comment: You will not be able to restrict that in the admin nop. Here it is in the roadmap https://portal.productboard.com/strapi/1-public-roadmap/c/8-administrators-roles-permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create custom policy which will compare authenticated user.id and requested profile user id and respond only if they are the same - read about creating policy here - [Strapi Policy Help](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/policies.html#how-to-create-a-policy)

```
    module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  const { body } = ctx.request
      if (ctx.state.user.id == ctx.request.query.userid || ctx.state.user.id == body.userid) {
        return await next();
      } 
      ctx.unauthorized(`You're not allowed to perform this action!`);
    };
```

Note that you have to insert userid field to the profile model. I had to use logical OR because I have different types of requests - it depends on your request only..